# TypeError: "Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined" when trying to .filter()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, typeerror

So i've been trying to troubleshoot this error and I've been coming up blank. I tried replacing title in .filter() with subreddit, key, link, type, and body, they all work fine without throwing an error, only title gives me the error. During troubleshooting I also placed that console.log to see if something was actually stored, and it printed the title to console like it should have, yet saved.title is still undefined in .filter. I also tried just saved.title.includes without toLowerCase() to no avail.

The code in question

```
  renderPostTitles = () => {
    const importantValues = this.props.totalUserSaves.map((saved) => {
      return { 
        subreddit: saved.data.subreddit, 
        title: saved.data.title, 
        key: saved.data.id, 
        link: `https://www.reddit.com${saved.data.permalink}`,
        type: saved.kind,
        body: saved.data.body
      }
    })

    console.log(importantValues[0].title)
    const threadsArray_searched = importantValues.filter(saved => saved.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.props.searchQuery.toLowerCase()) )
```

More of the component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class DisplaySaves extends React.Component {
  renderPostTitles = () => {
    const importantValues = this.props.totalUserSaves.map((saved) => {
      return { 
        subreddit: saved.data.subreddit, 
        title: saved.data.title, 
        key: saved.data.id, 
        link: `https://www.reddit.com${saved.data.permalink}`,
        type: saved.kind,
        body: saved.data.body
      }
    })

    const threadsArray_searched = importantValues.filter(saved => saved.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.props.searchQuery.toLowerCase()) )

    return threadsArray_searched.map((saved, i) => {
     return (
        <div key={saved.key}>
          <div> {i+1}. </div>
          <div> r/{saved.subreddit}: </div>
          <p> <a href={saved.link} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"> {saved.title} </a> </p>
        </div>
        )
    })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.renderPostTitles()}</div>
      </div>
      ) 
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log(state)
  return { 
    totalUserSaves: state.userData.totalUserSaves,
    searchQuery: state.userData.searchQuery
   }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(DisplaySaves);
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not `this.props.searchQuery.toLowerCase()` giving you grief?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, because like I said I tried the other values in place of title and there were no problems. Meaning the error disappeared, and everything worked as intended.

Comment: I would give `title: saved.data.title || ""` a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure title is a string in all cases (an undefined is possibly sneaking through in one of the elements), you could use a default or string constructor:

```
return {
  title: saved.data.title || '',
```

or

```
return {
  title: String(saved.data.title),
```

Comment: This was it. Not sure why it wasn't a string considering in the original data I got from reddit it was a string.